# Best way to detect corners of a plaque and reference object (Java, Opencv, Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv

first of all English is not my main language. So I'm sorry for any mistakes and also this is my first time using StackOverflow.

About my problem: I'm doing a research project at my college, where I have to create an app that is able to analyze an image of a plate and its reference object. And return the width and height of that plate using a picture taken with the app. I joined the project after it started so the app has to be made in android studio using java. The thing is, that my major is not in computer science. So maybe I don't have enough bag of knowledge, to know where to look and would like to know if you have tips on what I have to search for or anything that could help me .

Right now I'm doing the whole usual process of getting an object contour (threshold, blur, etc etc) and I have a really good threshold image.

[image: plaque]

[image: mask]

I'm getting the contour of the plaque just fine but I'm having trouble with the reference object (the A4 sheet). I'm currently using Imgproc.approxPolyDP and the sheet proportion to ensure that the outline is that of the sheet and not some other outline of the plate, but if I can make it work for a specific photo it doesn't work for the real-time picture on the app.

So do you guys have any tips? Or should I talk to my teacher for him to make some concessions? I thought about making an interface where the user could select the right contours and then calculate the height and width values ​​but my teacher is very difficult to accept changes in the project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could put down graph paper or sth else with known dimensions (even a blank sheet of paper, possibly colored/dyed for contrast), then hand-pick four points in the picture (automatic methods to detect "fiducials" do exist), and `getPerspectiveTransform` those corners from the picture into an ideal top-down view in which you can measure. or you could use ARUCO markers, which are more of a spatial thing. I'd recommend the homography. it's simple. I'd recommend fixing the camera. better results. if you can't do that, you'd need to take one picture with both the object and the "fiducials".

Comment: note: "fiducials" are those crash test dummy things. googling "opencv fiducials" shows a lot of ARUCO results. they would do of course, for picking 2D positions in a picture, but they were designed for more than that. you could generate four different aruco markers, arrange them on a page, print that, and then literally measure what the printer made. that's now your 2D "model", you'd use `getPerspectiveTransform` and the 2D "measurements" from the photo, and you'd transform the photo using `warpPerspective`.

Comment: Thank you so much, finished implementing it with the aruco markers and it worked really well!